# intellij idea setting user account for git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have imported a new project from our stash server using import from git.

As I want to commit there is nothing configured for the author. When I look in preferences menu for git there is nothing to configure for the user/password. Thus, I can't commit.

Should I configure the user/password via git by command line (I am using mac os x) or there is some settings to configure in intellij idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with IntelliJ, you have to set your username in GIT configuration:

```
git config --global user.name "user"
```

Check [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/) for more options like using repository specific usernames.

Comment: done but while commiting via intellij idea it says Error:No existing author found with 'myusername'